# Tuner Component: Is it possible to tune the batch size?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, hyperparameters, tfx

I'm currently using TFX to build a pipeline on the Google AI platform with the Kubeflow engine.
I have a model where the **batch size** is an important hyper-parameter to tune.

I would like to search this hyper-parameter in the **Tuner component**.

Is it even possible?

I follow the TFX example with the Penguin dataset, more precisely the tuner component implementation: [found here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/dd9829b0ac6e2dd708641ce39e7a3234a552d56b/tfx/examples/penguin/penguin_utils_cloud_tuner.py).

The `_get_hyperparameters` function returns the sample space for the model hyper-parameters ([see line 139](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/dd9829b0ac6e2dd708641ce39e7a3234a552d56b/tfx/examples/penguin/penguin_utils_cloud_tuner.py#L139)).
However, the batch size to train the model is fixed and specified at the end of the tuner_fn ([see line 246](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/dd9829b0ac6e2dd708641ce39e7a3234a552d56b/tfx/examples/penguin/penguin_utils_cloud_tuner.py#L246)).

Is there a way to **dynamically** change the **batch size** based on a sample from the hyper-parameter space?

Comment: Please check related github issue :- https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/3591